# php how to split an array string into two by condition

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a simple array of prices, which is formed as a result of data entry by users

```
    array(4) {
      [0] => string(4) "18"
      [1] => string(4) "20"
      [2] => string(4) "10"
      [3] => string(4) "17"
    }
```

The minimum and maximum values ​​are displayed in the frontend like 10-20$

But, in one field, the user can enter a range of values, like this:

```
    array(3) {
      [0]=> string(9) "18-28"
      [2]=> string(9) "10-15"
      [3]=> string(9) "16-22"
    }
```

And then the range is displayed as 10-15-18-28$

How to break the lines of array into two, if the line has a "-" or "/"?

Thanks for help:)

Comment: [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode)? However, please show a more concrete example of what you have as input, and what you want as output (and also, what you tried to do about it).

Comment: so what is your expected output then?

Comment: I want, if the array string contains characters "-" or "/" (like in two example up), then split it into two strings each and to get 10-28$ in frontend from this array as a result

Answer (score 0):

You might use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and use the dash or forward slash as the delimiter. If you want to display the highest and the lowest, you could sort them and use for example [rsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php).

```
$a = [
    "18-28",
    "18-29",
    "10-15",
    "16-22"
];
rsort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18-29
    [1] => 18-28
    [2] => 16-22
    [3] => 10-15
)
```

Then you can get the first item from the array as the highest and the last item as the lowest range.

```
echo reset($a).'$'; // 18-29$
echo end($a).'$'; // 10-15$
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/BHL4H)

Comment: This is a good idea for sorting, I will use it)  But, I need to get 10-29$ in frontend from this array as a result)

Comment: @Artem I have updated my answer to use rsort instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if natural sorting will hold up on all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `explode` and `implode`:

```php
$a = [
  '18-28',
  '10-15',
  '16-22'
];

$b = explode('-',implode('-',$a));
echo min($b).'-'.max($b).'$'; // result: 10-28$
```

If the input may also contain spaces or other dummy characters, or people erratically enter price ranges as "18/28" or "18~28" instead of "10-28" or whatever, a more fool-proof way would be:

```
$a = [
  // crappy formatted example input
  '18 - 28 ',
  '10/15$',
  ' 16~22'
];

$b = explode(' ',trim(preg_replace('#[^0-9.]+#si',' ',implode(' ',$a))));
echo min($b).'-'.max($b).'$'; // result: 10-28$
```

What this does is:

1. implode all elements of `$a` into a single string, glued together with spaces
2. replace all non-numeric parts of the string (anything that isn't a digit or dot) into a single space
3. trim the string to remove any redundant spaces at the beginning and end (to avoid empty elements)
4. explode the string using a space as separator, to create a new array containing all individual numbers
5. take the `min` and `max` of the resulting array

If you don't want to support floating point numbers (like `9.95`) then remove the dot in the regular expression, i.e. that becomes `'#[^0-9]+#si'`.

Comment: Pattern modifiers `s` and `i` are completely useless for these regex patterns.